# Excel TFS Add-In Crashes Connecting to TFS

Tags: excel, tfs, office365, add-in

We frequently use Excel to perform bulk updates of data in TFS. Up until very recently, the Team Foundation Add-In has worked very well. However, it has started failing in several ways:

- It will connect to the server, but attempting to connect to any
  project causes Excel to crash, producing a Watson report in the
  Windows Application Event Log.
- If I restart Excel, it reports that it is running into problems with
  both the shim and the add-in, and offers to disable it. If I do not
  disable it, I still can't connect to a project.
- Eventually, the add-in refuses to load at all, until I use the
  Options dialog to manually add the COM add-in back into the
  application. Doing so produces the same results (Excel crashes when
  attempting to load a project).

I have taken the following steps in an attempt to resolve the issue:

1. Removed and completely reinstalled Office.
2. Re-registered the add-in component.
3. Uninstalled and reinstalled Team Foundation Office Integration.

None of these have produced a fix to the issue.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

**P.S.** If this is not the correct "stack" for this question, kindly point me to the correct one on the exchange. Thank you.

Comment: More of a Super User question

Comment: Does this issue occur on other machines? Everything works as expected on my side. Suggest cleaning the caches on your client machine, including the TFS and VS caches : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsalm/2013/12/17/how-to-clear-the-tfs-cache-on-client-machines/

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT Clearing the cache resolved the problem handily! Please post this as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general cleaning the caches on your client machine will resolve such problems, including the TFS and VS caches...

To clean the caches, please see [How to clear the TFS cache on client machines](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsalm/2013/12/17/how-to-clear-the-tfs-cache-on-client-machines/)

Answer (score 6):

If you are reading the accepted answer and it still isn't working, here's an additional tip. I had the EXACT same problem and saw that same link to clear the cache from numerous sites, bit it didn't work.

Here's the thing. I don't think that article lists ALL of the places that cache can be hiding on your machine. I deleted the cache folder in two different places on my machine and had given up on that as a solution.

Then I searched my entire hard drive for any folder with "Team Foundation" in the name and found a couple more buried in other hierarchies. Deleting these FINALLY solved the problem.

Here are some folders to look for, but like I said, check the entire drive

```
c:\users\yourlogin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation
c:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft shared\Team Foundation Server\
c:\users\yourlogin\AppData\Local\Temp\Microsoft\Team Foundation
```

The actual cache folder will be nested another level deep under a numbered folder named with something like "7.0" or "8.0" delete the cache folder from every one you find under every number.